# Merging two docx files : bulleted list disappears

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I want to merge two docx documents.

The first one (test1.docx) contains :

[image]

And the second one (test2.docx) is empty.

I want to add first document content to second.

I am doing it like this:

```
String test1 = "test1.docx";
String test2 = "test2.docx";
String test3 = "test3.docx";

FileInputStream fisCv = new FileInputStream(test2);
OPCPackage packageFisCv = OPCPackage.open(fisCv);
XWPFDocument cvDocument = new XWPFDocument(packageFisCv);
CTBody cvDocumentBody = cvDocument.getDocument().getBody();

FileInputStream tmpIs = new FileInputStream(test1);
OPCPackage packageTemp = OPCPackage.open(tmpIs);
XWPFDocument tempDocument = new XWPFDocument(packageTemp);
CTBody tempBody = tempDocument.getDocument().getBody();
appendBody(cvDocumentBody, tempBody);
cvDocument.write(new FileOutputStream(test3));


private static void appendBody(CTBody src, CTBody append) throws Exception {
  XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
  optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();
  String appendString = append.xmlText(optionsOuter);
  String srcString = src.xmlText();
  String prefix = srcString.substring(0,srcString.indexOf(">")+1);
  String mainPart = srcString.substring(srcString.indexOf(">")+1,srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
  String suffix = srcString.substring( srcString.lastIndexOf("<") );
  String addPart = appendString.substring(appendString.indexOf(">") + 1, appendString.lastIndexOf("<"));
  CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+suffix);
  src.set(makeBody);
}
```

here is what I get in test3.docx

[image]

Bulleted list has disappear. Is there a way to avoid that?

Thanks

Comment: Removing the docx4j tag, since you are using POI.  Our commercial Docx4j Enterprise can do what you want.